Generate in development in <style> tag on SSR page
I'm really struggling to find best way how to make single html page containing all styles for its items.
How to get styles from css modules? Or maybe it is bad idea?
template = await fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8')
template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template)
render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule('/src/entry-server.tsx')).render
// how to get css here?
const rendered = await render(url, ssrManifest)

const html = template
  .replace(`<!--app-head-->`, rendered.head ?? '')
 .replace(`<!--app-html-->`, rendered.html ?? '')


There is two way to do this but i suggest this one by using vite-plugin-ssr for collecting css by using:
npm i vite-plugin-ssr

After installing you need to make some configuration change in you vite configuration as shown below:
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    modules: {
      scopeBehaviour: 'local',
    },
  },
  ssr: {
    noExternal: ['@vitejs/plugin-react'],
  },
})

then make some changes in you code like to collect css used during server side rendering and inject it into the HTML
import { renderPage } from 'vite-plugin-ssr'

const template = await fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8')
const { htmlRender, css } = await renderPage({ url })

const html = template
  .replace(`<!--app-head-->`, `<style>${css}</style>`)
  .replace(`<!--app-html-->`, htmlRender)

If still you have any issue you can comment down and i will check and see how i can help you.

Thank you for your answer. I like how simple Vite is allowing me to get string ReactDOMServer.renderToString() and return it with render function from my example.
The lib you proposed is now "Vike" and I don't like how complex it is to setup SSR only page with it.  It is not enough to just add render page and plugin. You have to add 'vike-react' or implement +onRenderHtml, routing and other functions. It looks to me there is to much convention with pages, naming files and layouts which I don't like. I like simple StaticRouter and my own component which render html.
